# AWS Elemental Media Converter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elemental

I am using AWS Elemental Media Converter to convert mp4 video from s3 bucket to m3u8 format. I have created custom output preset [image: Custom presets which I created]but I cannot see them while creating the job. [image: Presets option while creating job] Where is my custom presets how can i select them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out on my own. It appears to me that it was some glitch because somehow I cannot see them may be the list did not get refreshed or updated but today the preset list got updated and i can see my custom presets.